# Out of bounds error in Mancala move?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to make a Mancala game for my class and for the base code of dispersing the seeds here is what I have. K is what is passed for the position of the board that I am taking the seeds out of

Here is the initial code

```
public class Mancala {
    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 14;
    private static final int START_SEEDS=4;

    private int[] board;

    public Mancala(){
        board = new int[BOARD_SIZE];

        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
            board[i]=START_SEEDS;

        board[0]=0;
        board[BOARD_SIZE/2]=0;
    }

 public boolean makeMove(int k){
  int seeds = board[k];
    while(seeds>0){
                for(int i = k; i <= board.length; i++){

                    seeds--;
                    board[i]++;

                }

                }

            board[k] = seeds;
```

I keep getting an out of bounds error on board[i]++ ? Any idea?

Comment: We need more code showing how board is being declared/modified. Have you checked to see if `board[i]` exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: @EricG I edited my post

Comment: I think its `i <= board.length` should just be `i < board.length`

Comment: @EricG That gets rid of the outofbounds error, however, now if I call the method at a position of 4 for k, board[4] ends up being -6 at the end of the code. Also, should I make it int i = k + 1 because I do not want to add seeds to the initial space? But if I do i = k + 1 I get another out of bounds.

Comment: @JamesP I dont know what a `Mancala game` is, so i cant help anymore without an explanation of what youre trying to do with the `makeMove` function.

Comment: @EricG Here is the assignment. https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnx0c2NvbXB1dGVyc2NpZW5jZXxneDo3Y2UzYzQ3NjdmYTM4Mzgw

Comment: There is a lot of work left to be done on the assignment, you're going to have to try to work it out.

Comment: Please do not deface your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = k; i <= board.length; i++){
    seeds--;
    board[i]++;
}
```

If board.length == 14

the loop will be running

```
board[12]
board[13]
board[14] out of bounds here as board goes from 0-13
```

Fixed version

```
for(int i = k; i < board.length; i++){
    seeds--;
    board[i]++;
}
```

Comment: When I do this at the end of my code board[k] is -6. The while loop is not stopping the code when it gets to 0 for some reason. Also, how can I get it to not add seeds to board[k]? If I do int i = k then it will mess up the code because it's supposed to give seeds to the rest of the spaces.